# Python Flask SqlAlchemy Add Database Model Name dynamically in For Loop

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am not that familiar with Python and SQLAlchemy so please be patient :)

I need to capture if, within a FORM that holds multiple ICONS(files), one or more ICONS have been changed when editing the record.
To see which ICONS have been changed I created an Object holding the changes with "Database Model Name" as the "Key" and its "Value"

```
{'icon': <FileStorage: 'fire.png' ('image/png')>}
```

**key** = used as database model name

**value** = file.filename

now when I try the get the data within a for loop and add this data to the Database model, nothing happens and it looks like I am not really accessing variable "k" in the loop.

```
for k, v in notequalat.items():
                    responseteamdata.k = v.filename
```

My question is, how can I combine the Database model class "**responseteamdata**" and the variable "**k**" so that I can add the changes to the database model dynamically.

here is the full code:

```
if not notequalat:
            try:
                responseteamdata.title = title
                responseteamdata.abbreviation = abbreviation
                responseteamdata.isfireteam = booleanisfireteam
                responseteamdata.iconposition = newlatlng
                db.session.commit()
            except IntegrityError:
                db.session.rollback()
                db.session.close()
                res = make_response(jsonify("message ", "Error Updating the Team"), 500)
                return res
        else:
            responseteamdata.title = title
            responseteamdata.abbreviation = abbreviation
            responseteamdata.isfireteam = booleanisfireteam
            responseteamdata.iconposition = newlatlng
            
            for k, v in notequalat.items():
                responseteamdata.k = v.filename

            db.session.commit()
            dbevent = "updated"
        
        db.session.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to dynamically assign the Table Column Name the following command has been working for me:

```
setattr(DB-Object, ColumnName, Value)
```

which means in my case:

```
setattr(responseteamdata, k, v.filename)
```